# How to transfer props from parent to grandchild vue.js

Tags: javascript, object, vue.js

I have 3 components. Profile.vue - parent, Information.vue - child and Rempayment.vue - grandchild. In Profile.vue, I transfer data from api 
and passes them on to parent. Then i need the same to grandchild (rempayment.vue).

this is profile.vue:

```
<template>
<div>
<Nav />
<div v-if="repaid">
  <Repaid />
</div>
<div v-else>
  <Information :loan="detailsLoan" />
  <Timetable :loan="detailsLoan" :confirmed="confirmed" v-if="confirmed 
 >0" />
  <TimetableApplication :loan="loan" v-else-if="confirmed == 0" />
  <Documents :loan="detailsLoan" />
</div>
</div>
</template>

<script>
import co from "@/util/co.js";
import Nav from "@/scenes/ClientZone/components/Nav.vue";
import Information from "@/scenes/ClientZone/components/Information.vue";
import Timetable from "@/scenes/ClientZone/components/Timetable.vue";
import TimetableApplication from 
"@/scenes/ClientZone/components/TimetableApplication.vue";
import Documents from "@/scenes/ClientZone/components/Documents.vue";
export default {
components: {
Nav,
Information,
Timetable,
TimetableApplication,
Documents
},
methods: {},
data: function() {
return {
  loan: {},
  repaid: false,
  detailsLoan: { data: {}, schedule: {}, sum: {} },
  confirmed: 0
};
},
mounted() {
// all informations about loan
co.getLoanList(
  this.$store.getters.customer_id,
  this.$store.getters.token
).then(data => {
  if (data.status > 400) {
    this.$router.push({ name: "login" });
  } else {
    let _data = data.data;
    console.log(_data);
    this.loan = Object.values(_data).map(loan => {
      if (loan.confirmed == 0) {
        return loan;
      } else if (loan.debt > 0) {
        this.confirmed = loan.confirmed;
        return loan;
      } else if (loan.debt == 0) {
        this.repaid = true;
        return loan;
      }
    })[0];
  }
});
```

my information.vue:

```
 <template lang="pug">
  .main_box
  .main
    .container.flex
        .box
            .loan_info
                .info
                    a Loan ID
                    a Product
                    a Amount
                .details
                    a {{loan.data.id}}
                    a Crédito de {{loan.data.period / 30}} meses
                    a R$ {{loan.data.amount}}
            .loan_status
                .status
                    a Status: 
                .txt
                    a {{status}}
        Repayment(:loan="detailsLoan")
  </template>

  <script>
  import Repayment from "@/scenes/ClientZone/components/Repayment.vue";
 import co from "@/util/co.js";

 export default {
  name: "Information",
  components: {
 Repayment
  },
  data() {
 return {
  detailsLoan: { data: {}, schedule: {}, sum: {} }
 };
 },
computed: {
 status() {
   if (this.loan.data.delay > 0) {
    return "O pagamento do montante do empréstimo está atrasado"; 
 //Płatność kwoty pożyczki jest opóźniona
  }
  if (this.loan.data.debt > 0) {
    return "pożyczka jest aktywna";
  }
  if (this.loan.data.debt == 0) {
    return "pożyczka zatwierdzona";
  }
}
},
props: {
  loan: { type: Object, required: true }
 }
};
```

My rempayment.vue - grandchild

```
<template lang="pug">
.main_repayement
    .container
      .box_1(:style="veryfi")
        .box
          .pic
          .main_box
            .info 
              a Trwa weryfikacja wniosku
      .box_2(:style="delay")
        .box
          .pic
          .main_box
              .info
                  a Aktualnie do spłaty
              .amount 
                  a {{loan.l_amount}} PLN
          .details
              .loan
                  a Rata: 
                  a(v-for="loan in loan.schedule") {{loan.amount}}
              .interest
                  a Interesse por atraso: 
                  a R$ {{late_fee}}
          button(type="button" @click="change") Pago
      .box_3(:style="activeLoan")
        .box
          .pic
          .main_box
            .info 
              a Pożyczka aktywna
            .info_txt
              a Termin płatności raty upływa
              a {{showDate}}
 </template>

 <script>
 import co from "@/util/co.js";
  export default {
    name: "Repayment",
    data() {
    return {
    objectNone: {
    display: "none"
    },
    objectBlock: {
    display: "block"
    },
    red: "blue"
  };
  },
 props: {
  loan: { type: Object, required: true }
 },
```

So I tried to pass props loan from information to rempayment but it's still wrong. Can someone lead me to a solution.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to make small change, in information.vue you need to write **:loan="loan"** not :loan="detailsLoan". Hope it works.

information.vue:

```js
<template lang="pug">
  .main_box
  .main
    .container.flex
        .box
            .loan_info
                .info
                    a Loan ID
                    a Product
                    a Amount
                .details
                    a {{loan.data.id}}
                    a Crédito de {{loan.data.period / 30}} meses
                    a R$ {{loan.data.amount}}
            .loan_status
                .status
                    a Status: 
                .txt
                    a {{status}}
        Repayment(:loan="loan")
  </template>

  <script>
  import Repayment from "@/scenes/ClientZone/components/Repayment.vue";
 import co from "@/util/co.js";

 export default {
  name: "Information",
  components: {
 Repayment
  },
  data() {
 return {
  detailsLoan: { data: {}, schedule: {}, sum: {} }
 };
 },
computed: {
 status() {
   if (this.loan.data.delay > 0) {
    return "O pagamento do montante do empréstimo está atrasado"; 
 //Płatność kwoty pożyczki jest opóźniona
  }
  if (this.loan.data.debt > 0) {
    return "pożyczka jest aktywna";
  }
  if (this.loan.data.debt == 0) {
    return "pożyczka zatwierdzona";
  }
}
},
props: {
  loan: { type: Object, required: true }
 }
};
```

Comment: great. Now it's ok. But I don't understand why I should write loan not detailsLoan? So "loan" is my proper name?  Or it have to be taken from profile.vue props?

Comment: From profile.vue, you are sending loan as prop, that means you can access loan only not detailsLoan.

Answer (score 0):

We can use one of those solutions:

1. [Provide/inject](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#provide-inject)
2. [Vuex Store](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/) for sharing data between components

**NOTE:** The provide/inject binding are NOT reactive. But if observed objects are provided, they do remain reactive. [Read more](https://medium.com/@znck/provide-inject-in-vue-2-2-b6473a7f7816)